# How to replace values of a variable by the most frequent value in R

Tags: r

I am working with R and have a data frame that includes names and corresponding office addresses. But the addresses are not perfectly matched with names and I have to replace the wrong addresses based on the most frequent value. Here is an example:

```
ID   Clients ADDRESS    FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME
1     A       Cobben      Cui          Z 
2     B       Beerstaat   Cui          Z
3     C       River       Cui          Z
4     D       Cobben      Cui          Z
5     E       Cobben      Cui          Z
6     F       Cobben      Cui          Z
6     F       Hart        Mike         G
7     H       Hart        Mike         G
8     I       Sparren     Mike         G
```

And I would like a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID   Clients ADDRESS    FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME
1     A       Cobben      Cui          Z 
2     B       Cobben      Cui          Z
3     C       Cobben      Cui          Z
4     D       Cobben      Cui          Z
5     E       Cobben      Cui          Z
6     F       Cobben      Cui          Z
6     F       Hart        Mike         G
7     H       Hart        Mike         G
8     I       Hart        Mike         G
```

I think it can be done by creating a frequency table and I was wondering whether there is a less complicated method.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that easy. I like stefan's version.
Here is a possible alternative:

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(ADDRESS) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    left_join(df, by = c("ADDRESS")) %>%  
    group_by(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(ADDRESS = first(ADDRESS)) %>% 
    select(-n)
```

```
  ADDRESS    ID Clients FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
  <chr>   <int> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>    
1 Cobben      1 A       Cui        Z        
2 Cobben      4 D       Cui        Z        
3 Cobben      5 E       Cui        Z        
4 Cobben      6 F       Cui        Z        
5 Cobben      2 B       Cui        Z        
6 Cobben      3 C       Cui        Z        
7 Hart        6 F       Mike       G        
8 Hart        7 H       Mike       G        
9 Hart        8 I       Mike       G
```

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` approach using `add_count` and `which.max` may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  add_count(LAST_NAME, ADDRESS) %>% 
  group_by(LAST_NAME) %>% 
  mutate(ADDRESS = ADDRESS[which.max(n)]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#>      ID Clients ADDRESS FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
#>   <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1     1 A       Cobben  Cui        Z        
#> 2     2 B       Cobben  Cui        Z        
#> 3     3 C       Cobben  Cui        Z        
#> 4     4 D       Cobben  Cui        Z        
#> 5     5 E       Cobben  Cui        Z        
#> 6     6 F       Cobben  Cui        Z        
#> 7     6 F       Hart    Mike       G        
#> 8     7 H       Hart    Mike       G        
#> 9     8 I       Hart    Mike       G
```

**DATA**

```
d <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Clients = c(
  "A",
  "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F", "H", "I"
), ADDRESS = c(
  "Cobben",
  "Beerstaat", "River", "Cobben", "Cobben", "Cobben", "Hart", "Hart",
  "Sparren"
), FIRST_NAME = c(
  "Cui", "Cui", "Cui", "Cui", "Cui",
  "Cui", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike"
), LAST_NAME = c(
  "Z", "Z", "Z",
  "Z", "Z", "Z", "G", "G", "G"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -9L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `base R` - use the [`Mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307703/how-to-add-new-column-in-r-data-frame-showing-sum-of-a-value-in-a-current-row-an/70307719?noredirect=1#comment124294327_70307719) on 'ADDRESS'  grouping by 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME' in `ave`

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

df1$ADDRESS <- with(df1, ave(ADDRESS, FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, FUN = Mode))
```

-output

```
> df1
  ID Clients ADDRESS FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
1  1       A  Cobben        Cui         Z
2  2       B  Cobben        Cui         Z
3  3       C  Cobben        Cui         Z
4  4       D  Cobben        Cui         Z
5  5       E  Cobben        Cui         Z
6  6       F  Cobben        Cui         Z
7  6       F    Hart       Mike         G
8  7       H    Hart       Mike         G
9  8       I    Hart       Mike         G
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), 
Clients = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F", "H", "I"), ADDRESS = c("Cobben", 
"Beerstaat", "River", "Cobben", "Cobben", "Cobben", "Hart", "Hart", 
"Sparren"), FIRST_NAME = c("Cui", "Cui", "Cui", "Cui", "Cui", 
"Cui", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike"), LAST_NAME = c("Z", "Z", "Z", 
"Z", "Z", "Z", "G", "G", "G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```